# Elements escaped in Enumeration

Tags: java, swing, enumeration, jtree

I have developed an application to search a node in a JTree  e.g if I search for A1 node,the TreePath is Root,A,A1.Here node A should be retained and the other children of Root(B,C,D,E) should be removed from Root.

The problem is that when I enter A1 nodes A,B and D are checked if they are part of the TreePath based on which they are either retained or deleted from the root(here A is retained whereas B and D are deleted from the Root).But C and E are missed from the Enumeration and are not checked if they constitute the TreePath.I have debugged the application and it fetched "D" after "B" and not "C".

I have printed all the children of Root which gives the result -A B C D E
But while iterating through the collection C and E are missed.Could someone provide a solution.

**The JTree**

[image]

```
{
            String key = field.getText().trim();
            System.out.println("Key entered is " + key);
            boolean deleteNode=true;
            TreePath path = searchNode(key);
            int count=path.getPathCount();
            DefaultMutableTreeNode[] nodes=new DefaultMutableTreeNode[count];
            for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
            {
            nodes[i]=(DefaultMutableTreeNode) path.getPathComponent(i);
            }
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nodes));
            if (path != null) 
            {  

        TreeModel model = tree.getModel();
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) model.getRoot();
        Enumeration children=root.children();
        while(children.hasMoreElements())
        {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node=(DefaultMutableTreeNode)children.nextElement();
        System.out.println(node.toString());
        }
        children=root.children();
        while(children.hasMoreElements())
        { 

        deleteNode=true;
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node=(DefaultMutableTreeNode)children.nextElement();
        System.out.println(node.toString());
        String nodeName=(String) node.getUserObject();
        for(int i=0;i<nodes.length;i++)
        {
        String temp=(String)nodes[i].getUserObject();
        if(temp.equalsIgnoreCase(nodeName))
        {
            System.out.println(node.toString()+" is  part of Tree Path");  
            deleteNode=false;
            break;


        }   
        }
        if(deleteNode)
        {
        System.out.println(node.toString()+" is not the part of Tree Path");   
        root.remove(node);

        }
        }



            DefaultTreeModel newModel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
            clonedTree.setModel(newModel);
            clonedTree.expandPath(path);//expand a node 
            clonedTree.setSelectionPath(path);//make it node visible
            System.out.println("match found");

        } else 
        {
            System.out.println("match is'nt found");
            removeSubTree();
        }



    }
```

Output-

A
B
C
D
E

A
A is  part of Tree Path
B
B is not the part of Tree Path
D
D is not the part of Tree Path

Comment: Post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help.

Comment: @alex2410:Everything is working fine when I used Iterator instead of a Enumeration.I dont know the reason though.